# How can I handle exceptions with Spring Data Rest and the PagingAndSortingRepository?

Tags: java, exception, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Let's say I have a repository like:

```
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    @Query("....")
    Page<MyEntity> findByCustomField(@Param("customField") String customField, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This works great.  However, if the client sends a formed request (say, searching on a field that does not exist), then Spring returns the exception as JSON.  Revealing the `@Query`, etc.

```
// This is OK
http://example.com/data-rest/search/findByCustomField?customField=ABC

// This is also OK because "secondField" is a valid column and is mapped via the Query
http://example.com/data-rest/search/findByCustomField?customField=ABC&sort=secondField

// This throws an exception and sends the exception to the client
http://example.com/data-rest/search/findByCustomField?customField=ABC&sort=blahblah
```

An example of the exception thrown and sent to client:

```
{
    message:null,
    cause: {
        message: 'org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: blahblah...'
    }
}
```

How can I handle those exceptions?  Normally, I use the `@ExceptionHandler` for my MVC controllers but I'm not using a layer between the Data Rest API and the client.  Should I?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a global [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) with the [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation. Basically, you define which Exception to handle with @ExceptionHandler within the class with @ControllerAdvice annotation, and then you implement what you want to do when that exception is thrown.

Like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({QueryException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> yourExceptionHandler(QueryException e) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("message", "Bad Request");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); //Bad Request example
    }
}
```

See also: https://web.archive.org/web/20170715202138/http://www.ekiras.com/2016/02/how-to-do-exception-handling-in-springboot-rest-application.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [@ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) and render the content your way. Here is tutorial if you need know how to work on `ControllerAdvice`, just remember to return `HttpEntity`

Comment: Link to the tutorial is missing