# Spring Data Rest exception handling - Return generic error response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I want to know how can I handle internal server error type exceptions in Spring Data Rest such as JPA exceptions etc. due to a malformed request or a database crash. I did some research found that the better way to do this is by using @ControllerAdvice but couldn't find any working example of it. I looked at both these questions but they are still unanswered.

[How can I handle exceptions with Spring Data Rest and the PagingAndSortingRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150688/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-with-spring-data-rest-and-the-pagingandsortingreposi)

[global exception handling for rest exposed spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331770/global-exception-handling-for-rest-exposed-spring-data)

Can someone help me with a working example of how to use @ControllerAdvice and write a custom error response back to client whenever there is an exception.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity handle(Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity("Some message", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I do it for all request validation errors,

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {

     @ExceptionHandler
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
     public ResponseBean handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception){

        StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
        ResponseBean response = new ResponseBean();

        int count = 1;
        for(ObjectError error:exception.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()){
            messages.append(" "+count+"."+error.getDefaultMessage());
            ++count;
        }

        response.setMessage(messages.toString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

where `ResponseBean` is my application specific class.

For JPA errors , exceptions are RuntimeExceptions and top level Exception is - `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException` .

If you wish to send a generic message to client, there is no need to catch - rethrow in your DAO, Service or Controller Layer. Just add an exception handler as above for `DataAccessException` and you are done.

If you wish to set specific messages for client for specific exceptions, you need to write an application specific exception hierarchy extending `DataAccessException` , lets say `MyAppJPAException` . You need to catch - `DataAccessException` in your application code ( either at DAO, Service or Controller layer ) and re throw `MyAppJPAException` . `MyAppJPAException` should have a custom message field where you should set your custom message before re throwing. In `MyAppJPAException` handler, you set that message in response and can set HTTP Status as - `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`

Comment: "@ControllerAdvice" is a specialization of "@Component", so you shouldn't add it at the top of the class.

Comment: what do you mean about quoted part? I have edited my answer to use `@RestControllerAdvice` though.

Comment: ok, Sabir. please look at the source code of "@ControllerAdvice"
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html
which says there's no use adding "@Component" allng with it.
BTW using "@RestControllerAdvice" you don't need to use "@ResponseBody" in the class anymore:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html