# How to handle exception from Spring Data Rest Resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I use `@RestResource` in my Spring Data Rest web application. And I would like to custom 404 error of my `RestResource`.

I'm aware of ControlerAdvice, handler... BUT **it doesn't work with RestResource**.

I already tried a lot of things :

- Set setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound to true with a bean or in application.properties
- Disable spring.resources.add-mappings=false in application.properties
- Add basePackages or basePackageClass on ControllerAdvice
- Extends RepositoryRestExceptionHandler (but I can't override it because method are package private)

My current source code is :

```
@RestResource(path="user")
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

    User findById(Long id);

}
```

-

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ErrorHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    ResponseEntity<?> handleNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal server error");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getHttpStatus());
    }

}
```

**Edit 1 (my question isn't a duplicate):**

I also try to add a new RestControllerAdviceHandler like this (but it doesn't work) :

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerAdviceHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(" test ", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

**Edit 2 (about spring framework source code):**

After more research in spring source code I find the code below. It seems that if entity is not found, no exception is raised, RestResource just returned a new ResponseEntity>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)). Maybe it's really impossible to intercept and customize the Not Found error with RestResource ?

```
/**
     * <code>GET /{repository}/{id}</code> - Returns a single entity.
     * 
     * @param resourceInformation
     * @param id
     * @return
     * @throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_MAPPING + "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource<?>> getItemResource(RootResourceInformation resourceInformation,
            @BackendId Serializable id, final PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers)
            throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {

        return getItemResource(resourceInformation, id).map(it -> {

            PersistentEntity<?, ?> entity = resourceInformation.getPersistentEntity();

            return resourceStatus.getStatusAndHeaders(headers, it, entity).toResponseEntity(//
                    () -> assembler.toFullResource(it));

        }).orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<Resource<?>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
```

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to accomplish here? Surely you're not trying to turn ordinary 404s into 500s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data Rest exception handling - Return generic error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245129/spring-data-rest-exception-handling-return-generic-error-response)

Comment: I try to transform 404 response empty body in

Comment: @luboskrnac Answer doesn't work for me...

Comment: @chrylis I try to transform 404 response empty body in a structured json body. Any idea ?

Comment: @luboskrnac It's not a duplicate because I'm using ```@RestResource``` and it's my problem !

Comment: @jeremieca 404 is supported inbuilt with spring-data-rest in absence of a path parameter. Can you pls tell wht is the situation you experience it is not working?? pls show your endpoint.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne 404 works but i want to custom 404 response body with my own json.

Comment: @jeremieca what you want to show? just update with an example pls

Comment: @SupunWijerathne We have similar state, when Entity is not Found, we would like to tell Entity doesn't Exist as a blank 404 may not make much sense for all business purposes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jeremieca Did you manage to get any solution? Thanks.

Comment: @shivaspk There is no answer... So, I found a workaround... I create a component class extending ```org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter``` and I intercept all response where the body don't start with "{". So all request that are not json formatted. Then, I replace the body of response with a json. I combine request url and statusCode to find the errorMessage. It's not perfect at all but it works... Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like it has been marked as a bug and hopefully addressed in future. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1143?jql=text%20~%20%22spring%20data%20rest%20404%22

Comment: @jeremieca I'm also dealing with this issue and spent most of yesterday looking for any possible way to do this, so I appreciate the update. My plan currently is to do this with ControllerAdvice through extending ResponseBodyAdvice<ResponseEntity<MyClassNameHere>>, which gives me access to the response before it's sent, but that also requires deducing it from URL + statusCode just like you and even then there's a search with two parameters that I can't clearly give information on.

Comment: @J.Marciano Thanks for the information ! Do you check that your ResponseBodyAdvice is called on 404 ? I'm not sure. But if it's right, it's really interesting. I think that ResponseBodyAdvice is more high level than OncePerRequestFilter.

Comment: @shivaspk Thank you for the link. It's extremely disappointing to see that a pull request was made a month after the bug was noticed a year ago, and it still hasn't been accepted. Hopefully one day we'll be able to do this easily.

Comment: @jeremieca Yes, it's definitely called when I test with it and I can change the returned body to a new subclass of ResponseEntity with an error message, though I haven't finished the work yet so something may go wrong from here. (I also think I should maybe just use Object instead of the class that was "MyClassNameHere", as it should handle a couple different kinds of ResponseEntity? It's not very clear how some of it works, especially as it still doesn't give me access to much beyond the status and request, etc., either.)

Comment: @J.Marciano ok thanks ! If possible stay me in touch. I’m very interrested by your solution !

Answer (score 1):

This is finally fixed in Spring Data REST's upcoming release 3.2.

A `ResourceNotFoundException` exception is thrown, which can now properly be intercepted.
Your solution using `@ControllerAdvice` will work.

Tested with Spring Boot 2.2.0 M2 and the following ExceptionHandler:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomRepositoryRestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity<?> handleNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException o_O) {
        // Simply re-throw the exception and let the default handling kick in, which will produce a response body.
        throw o_O;
    }
}
```

As already posted in the comments, the issue is https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1143 .